# Add info from variable number of files to python class and subclasses

Tags: python, class, subclass

This may be a very beginner question, but I never used classes in python before and would love to get some help.

I am going through a list of files of genes with associated information. I would like to create a class for Genes similar to:

```
class Gene:
def __init__(self, name):
   self.name = name
```

To add information for each gene I need to specify which file it's coming from say FileA or FileB (can have variable number of files). I assume I would need to add a subclass to do this but am not sure. Thinking along the lines of:

```
class GeneFileInfo (Gene):
    def __init__(self, Gene, File, expression, value):
        self.Gene = Gene
        self.File = File
        self.LogFC = expression
        self.LogCPM = value
    def getGeneInfo(self):
        print Gene+"\t"+File+"\t"+expression+"\t"+value
```

I would also like to add a function to print all the information on the Gene.

For instance when I call the function getGeneInfo(Gene) I would like to print the Gene name, value and Expression for each file.

In the long run I would like to loop through a list of Genes and write to a file all the information on that gene coming from all the individual input files.

Comment: So what exactly *is* your question? Have you *tried* your subclass? [Read the docs?](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: The second part of your question is quite broad, and it should be posted (with more information about *what* should be printed) as a separate question.

Comment: So GeneInfo *is A* Gene? No, right? Gene *HAS A* GeneInfo. You need composition here, over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to maintain a mapping between a single instance of `Gene` (representing a particular gene) and the names of one or more files that contain information about that gene. You can do this by simply adding another attribute to `Gene`:

```
class Gene:

    def __init__(self, name, files=None):
       self.name = name
       if files is None:
           files = []
       self.files = files

x = Gene("methuselah", ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"])

# Or set the file list later
y = Gene("sickle")
y.files.append("file_a.txt")
```